# Sequential Test: If $\forall x_n \in D\backslash\{c\}, \lim_{n\to \infty}x_n = c \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)=L$, then $\lim_{x\to c}f(x) = L$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I was trying to understand the proof from lecture notes.

> Prove: If $\forall x_n \in D\backslash\{c\}, \lim_{n\to \infty}x_n = c \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)=L$, then $\lim_{x\to c}f(x) = L$.

The solution was written as follows:

> Assume $\lim_{x \to c}f(x) \neq L$, then the negation is true:
>
> $\implies \exists \epsilon_0 >0$ st. $\forall \delta >0$, $\exists x$ st. $0<|x-c|<\delta$ while $|f(x)-L| \geq \epsilon_0$.  **(1)**
>
> $\implies \forall n$, $\exists x_n$ st. $0<|x_n -c| < \frac{1}{n}$ while $|f(x_n)-L|\geq \epsilon_0$  **(2)**
>
> But $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n =c \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) =L$ but contradict $|f(x_n)-L|\geq \epsilon_0$  so $\lim_{x \to c}f(x) = L$

**I don't understand how the proof goes from (1) to (2).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1)$ says that for each positive $\delta$ there is an $x$ with a certain property; $(2)$ just makes that claim only for those values of $\delta$ that can be written in the form $\frac1n$ for some positive integer $n$. If the claim holds for all positive $\delta$, then it certainly holds for all $\frac1n$.

In more detail, $(1)$ says that there is some $\epsilon_0>0$ such that no matter what $\delta>0$ I pick, there is some $x_\delta$ such that $0<|x_\delta-c|<\delta$, but $|f(x_\delta)-L|\ge\epsilon_0$. For each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, therefore, $0<|x_{1/n}-c|<\frac1n$, but $|f(x_{1/n})-L|\ge\epsilon_0$. Line $(2)$ simply relabels what I’ve called $x_{1/n}$ as $x_n$.

Comment: I understand that we make $\delta = \frac{1}{n}$, but I don't know how to transit from the real number x to the sequence $x_n$

Comment: @Fan: In the notation that I used, the sequence is simply $\langle x_{1/n}:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$, i.e., $\langle x_1,x_{1/2},x_{1/3},\ldots\rangle$. Now just rename $x_{1/n}$ to $x_n$.

Comment: I see, so **(1)** becomes, $\implies \exists \epsilon_0 >0$ st. $\forall \frac{1}{n} >0$, $\exists x$ st. $0<|x-c|<\frac{1}{n}$ while $|f(x)-L| \geq \epsilon_0$. Then the 'x' in this case is a sequence under $\delta = \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: @Fan: It would be better to write $\forall n\ge 1$ instead of $\forall\frac1n>0$: the object immediately following the quantifier should be a plain variable symbol. Apart from that, however, you’re correct.